# CRC lookup table generated in C always gives different results

Tags: c, memory, crc, lookup-tables

I'm trying to create a function that generates a CRC lookup table. I'm working with an 8051 micro-controller, and I'd rather do the table lookup method but at the same time, I'd rather have my computer generate the values which then I can load directly into the micro-controller. Most of this source code has been borrowed from: http://www.rajivchakravorty.com/source-code/uncertainty/multimedia-sim/html/crc8_8c-source.html

I only added in the "main" function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GP  0x107
#define DI  0x07

static unsigned char crc8_table[256];
static int made_table=0;

static void init_crc8()
{
  int i,j;
  unsigned char crc;
  if (!made_table) {
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
      crc = i;
      for (j=0; j<8; j++)
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((crc & 0x80) ? DI : 0);
      crc8_table[i] = crc & 0xFF;
    }
    made_table=1;
  }
}

void crc8(unsigned char *crc, unsigned char m)
{
  if (!made_table)
    init_crc8();
  *crc = crc8_table[(*crc) ^ m];
  *crc &= 0xFF;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char crc[1];
  crc8(crc,'S');
  printf("S=%x\n",crc[0]); //different hex code almost every time
  crc8(crc,'T');
  printf("T=%x\n",crc[0]); //different hex code almost every time
  return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program, I expected the same values on the screen but the hex codes after the printed equals signs changed on nearly every program execution.

What can I do to correct that issue? I don't want to be collecting incorrect CRC values.

Comment: Remember that local variable (including arrays) are by default *uninitialized*. Their values will be *indeterminate*. Now think about that in the context of the `crc` array in the `main` function.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should probably learn about the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: @Somepro: Could you be more specific about the `&`?

Comment: Instead of using an array to be able to pass a pointer, use a simple `unsigned char crc;` and then use `&crc` to get a pointer. As in `crc8(&crc, 'S')`. An even better solution IMO would be to *not* emulate *pass by reference* and instead have the `crc8` function *return* the value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Would anybody like to make an answer? Just to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main, crc[0] has not been initialized.  As a result, in crc8, *crc in the expression **(*crc) ^ m** is uninitialized, hence your random values.

Fix: initialize crc[0].  Something like

```
unsigned char crc[1] = { 0 };
```

Comment: That does work, but what I tried that didn't work was: `crc[0]='\0'; crc[1]='\0';` since it gave me a segmentation fault. I'm baffled as to why your solution works but apparently it does.

Comment: `crc[1] = '\0';` is _not_ the same as `unsigned char crc[1] = {0};`. The former is an out-of-bounds access since it tries to set the _second_ element of `crc[]`, but there is no second element since it was declared with one element. Such an access should result in a segmentation fault. The latter is an initialization of an one-element array with one value, which sets `crc[0]` to zero.

Answer (score 2):

1. `crc[0]` is not initialized. You need `crc[0] = 0;` or `*crc = 0;` before calling `crc8()` with `crc`. Then you won't get random answers coming from the random initial contents of `crc[0]`.
2. You don't need the `*crc &= 0xff;` in `crc8()`. If `char` is eight bits, then it does nothing. If you have an odd architecture where `char` is more than eight bits, then you need to do `*crc = crc8_table[((*crc) ^ m) & 0xff];` to assure that you don't go outside the bounds of the table. (Only the low eight bits of `m` will be used in the CRC calculation.) The contents of the table have already been limited to eight bits, so in any case you don't need a final `& 0xff`.
3. You may need a different initial value than zero, and you may need to exclusive-or the final CRC value with something, depending on the definition of the CRC-8 that you want. In the [RevEng catalog of CRC's](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm), there are two 8-bit CRCs with that polynomial that are not reflected. Both happen to start with an initial value of zero, but one is exclusive-ored with `0x55` at the end. Also the CRC definition you need may be reflected, in which case the shift direction changes and the polynomial is flipped. If your CRC-8 needs to be interoperable with some other software, then you need to find out the full definition of the CRC being used.
4. Passing a pointer seems like an odd choice here. It would be more efficient to just pass and return the CRC value directly. E.g. `unsigned crc8(unsigned crc, unsigned ch) {`, which would apply the eight bits in `ch` to the CRC `crc`, and return the new value. Note that you do not need to make the CRC value a `char`. `unsigned` is generally what C routines most efficiently take as an argument and return. In fact usually the first argument is passed in a register and returned in the same register.
5. Usually one computes a CRC on a message consisting of a series of bytes. It would be more efficient to have a routine that does the whole message with a loop, so that you don't need to check to see if the table has been built yet for every single byte of the message.